# ETL package works in Dev but not in Production

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I have an on-premise SQL Server running a job with an ETL package and pointing to a SQL Server database in Azure.

In DEV, it works fine, but then when we copy the package to PROD and try to run it, it fails.

The error message returned by the job is the following:

```
Error: 2023-01-06 08:10:53.83     Code: 0xC0208452     Source: ETL Destino ADO NET [8]     
Description: ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection with the following error message: "One or more errors occurred.".  End Error  

Error: 2023-01-06 08:10:53.83     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: ETL SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Destino de ADO NET failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208452.  End Error  

Error: 2023-01-06 08:10:53.83     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: ETL SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  

Error: 2023-01-06 08:10:53.83     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: ETL    Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  

DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:10:51 AM Finished: 8:10:53 AM Elapsed:  1.953 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.**
```

It runs under the SQL Server Agent service account, which has `db_owner` permissions within the Azure database. The same permissions as the Development account, which does work.

The source instances are both SQL Server 2017, CU25.

The packages are located locally in both of the servers.

Does anyone have any idea?

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but did you check that your firewall is correctly configured on both servers?

Comment: Managed instance, Azure SQL DB, or a VM hosted in Azure that has SQL Server on it? When you "copy the package to PROD" how exactly is that task performed? The connection to the ADO.NET destination - does that use a domain user, Azure AD user, or a SQL User? How are credentials handled?